# How to avoid nesting structure of callbacks with promises? [finished]

Tags: javascript, express, promise, passport.js

I am using promises to avoid the nesting structure created by callbacks.

However in this code I still have some nesting.  Is there something I am doing wrong or is this un-avoidable in this case?

In this case I want to check and see if a profile exists and if it does not I want to create it.

```
  DB.getProfile(id_google).then((resGet) => {
    if(!resGet[0]){
      console.log('PROFILE - NOT FOUND - MUST CREATE');

      DB.createProfile(id_google, email, name, pic_url).then((resCreate)=>{
        console.log('PROFILE CREATED');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR - createProfile() Failed: ', error);
      });

    } else {
      console.log('PROFILE FOUND LOCALLY');
      console.log(resGet[0]);
      return done(null, resGet[0])
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR - getOrCreateProfile() Failed: ', error);
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you ok with using async/await instead of promises in your application?

Comment: Yes, [nesting is pretty much unavoidable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21578854/1048572) for conditional statements.

Comment: You really should `return` from all your functions (to make a promise) instead of calling that `done` callback. That way, you wouldn't forget to call it (when an profile is created).

Comment: @boysimpledimple async/await is not used "instead" of promises. It is used *with* promises, instead of `then` callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that's true. Async/Await is a syntactical wrapper for promises that makes regular control structures easier to use.

Comment: you need to get `id_google, email, name, pic_url` from `resGet `?

Comment: If you think that then I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664598/async-function-not-returning-value-but-console-log-does-how-to-do/47678417#47678417). It explains why callback/promises are used and how to use them. Your function resolves in undefined in case `resGet[0]` being falsy and when getProfile rejects.

Comment: @mikejacques It avoided nesting an inner `then` by simply dropping the `console.log('PROFILE CREATED')`

Answer (score 4):

You can return and chain using multiple `then`

```
DB.getProfile(id_google)
    .then((resGet) => {
        if (!resGot[0]) {
            return DB.createProfile(id_google, email, name, pic_url);
        }
        return resGot[0];
    })
    .then((res) => {
        callback(null, res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR - getOrCreateProfile() Failed: ', error);
    });
```

If `resGot[0]` exist, then it is returned, and in the second `then` the variable `res` is that value. If it does not, then the promise of `createProfile` is returned and the value of `res` is whatever that function returns

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to boil your code down to the essentials:

```
getProfile
  if not found, 
    createProfile
       return profile
  else
    done profile
```

Presumably, you want to get `createProfile` outside in the same chain as the rest of the promise.

I changed the structure to:

```
getProfile
  if found, return profile 
  createProfile
    return profile
then
  done(profile)
```

It isn't really possible to have just one degree of nesting in this case. But you can reduce some level of nesting.

```
DB.getProfile(id_google)
.then((resGet) => {
    if(resGet[0]) {
      console.log('PROFILE FOUND LOCALLY');
      return resGet[0];
    }
    console.log('PROFILE - NOT FOUND - MUST CREATE');
    return DB.createProfile(id_google, email, name, pic_url)
    .then((resCreate)=>{
      console.log('PROFILE CREATED');
      return resCreate[0]; //Assuming resCreate looks like resGet
    })
  }
})
.then(profile=> {
    //The done function which belongs to passport is called once here.
    console.log(profile);
    return done(null, resGet[0])
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR - getOrCreateProfile() Failed: ', error);
});
```