# How can i break my promise chain in certain reject cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chain

I have a chain of promises, where certain things happen on resolve and different things happen on reject, however sometimes I want to skip all the following `then` statements.

My code looks like this

```
await req.reduce((promise, audit) => {
    let globalData;
  return promise.then(_ => this.add(audit)
      .then((data)=> {
                          globalData = data; console.log('1'); 
                          return dropbox_functions.createFolder(data.ui, data)
                     }, 
           (error)=> {
                          failed.push({audit: audit, error: 'There was an error adding this case to the database'}); 
                          console.log('1.1'); i = i + 1; socket.emit('bulkAddUpdate', i/arrLen); 
                          throw new Error('There was an error adding this case to the database');
                     })
       .then((data)=>{
                         console.log('2');
                         return dropbox_functions.checkScannerFolderExists(audit.scanner_ui)
                     },
            (error)=>{
                         console.log('2.1');issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'There was an error creating the case folder in dropbox'}); 
                         i = i + 1;socket.emit('bulkAddUpdate', i/arrLen); 
                         throw new Error('There was an error creating the case folder in dropbox');
                     })
       .then((data)=>{
                         console.log('3');
                         return dropbox_functions.moveFolder(audit.scanner_ui, globalData.ui)},
            (error)=>{
                         console.log('3.1');issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'No data folder was found so an empty one was created'}); 
                         return dropbox_functions.createDataFolder(globalData.ui)
                     })
       .then(()=>    {
                         console.log('4');
                         success.push({audit:globalData}); 
                         i = i + 1;socket.emit('bulkAddUpdate', i/arrLen);},
          (error)=> {
                         issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'Scanner folder found but items not moved'});console.log('4.1');
                    })
      .catch(function(error){
              console.log(error)
            })
    );
  }, Promise.resolve()).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
```

In the first then if the code goes into the reject case, I want to skip all the remaining thens. However it doesn't and therefore all the subsequent then happen and all fail. The only reject that should move on is in the 3rd then when I do want to return a promise.

Comment: `.catch` is just a glorified `.then`. It calls it internally.

Comment: Don't mix raw promises with async/await unless needed. It just makes everything complicated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean please estus. The reason I do what I do is because there is throttling on the dropbox api, so i need to do things one by one

Comment: @ArthurLeCalvez You should just use a `for (const audit in req) { … await … }` loop. There's [rarely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572) a need to use `then` when you can just use `await`.

Comment: See also [How to properly break out of a promise chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500221/1048572), [how to break promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28803287/1048572) or [Proper way to skip a then function in Q Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21576862/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

In general, your problem is that some errors are fatal and some are not. You want fatal errors to fall all the way to the bottom, but non-fatal errors to be handled in sequence.

Keep all your "fatal" errors at top level, and nest the non-fatal ones inside the then block. I also suggest *never* using the "then(fn,fn)" format - always specify your catches explicitly.

Example:

```
return fnA().then(dataA => {
    return fnB(dataA).catch(error => {
        console.log("fnB got a non-fatal error, I'm fixing it.");
        return fnFixB();
    });
})
.then(dataB => fnC())
.then(dataC => {
    return fnD(dataC).catch(error => {
        console.log("fnD didn't work, I'm fixing it.");
        return fnFixD();
    });
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Sorry: one of fnA, fnFixB, fnC, or fnFixD must have broken.");
});
```

In this example, if `fnA` or `fnC` reject, you're dropping to the bottom; but, `fnB` and `fnD` produce errors that you can potentially recover from (although if your fixes `fnFixB` and `fnFixD` fail, you'll drop to the bottom as well).

Also, I would suggest breaking your breaking your code into smaller methods for readability: check out the article [Error handling in long Promise chains](https://medium.com/@arthurxavier/error-handling-in-long-promise-chains-155f610b5bc6) for a great little example very similar to yours.